# How can I store 0xFF to a char in C?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, int, hex

How can I store something in this format: "0xff" to a char array after declaring the array. I'll demonstrate what I mean below.

When writing a code such as this, works just fine:

```
 int main (void){
       unsigned char array[] = {0xff,0xa4};
       return 0;
 }
```

But, what I need is slightly more complicated. I need to assign something such as 0xff to the array after having already declared it. How can I get this to work and obtain the exact same result as in the piece of code above? With the code below I keep receiving the error "`multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`" and "`large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]`".

```
int main(void){
      unsigned char array[2];
      array[0] = '0xff';
      array[1] = '0xa4';
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you suddenly put them in single-quotes?

Comment: @Yunnosch can you be more specific? Where do I use  `\xff`?

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: Q: How come `int i = 1;` works but `int i; i = "1";` doesn't? How can I store `1` to `i` after declaring it? A: use `int i; i = 1;`

Comment: @immibis,    you seem to have some confusion about how to declare a integer `1`  and how to declare a string `"1"`

Comment: @user3629249 The question has the same confusion. That's the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `array[0] = '\xff';` to set a single char to a hex numerical.
Or  `array[0] = 0xff;` as you did in the first part of your code, successfully.